# returning from mollie payment

Tags: civievent, mollie

my organisation has a site on which payed events are offered. Visitors can pay via an IDEAL mollie payment with use of a custom build module.
We want to replace that module by making use of the civicrm mollie interpay module.

Up to now, we have been unsuccessful in  testing this module. The test payments don't work at all, while production payments do work, but not yet in a way that we can use it in our site.

I hope you can guide me in making the production payments work.

The site is a wordpress based site. We use civicrm 5.18.3. For payment we use the interpay (mollie) method.

When a payment is done with mollie, the payment is registered and visible in the event dashboard. So the most important part works. But the user who has finished the payment (and clicks the 'back to webshop' button) gets a blank screen.
The URL of that blank screen ends with `wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fpayment%2Fipn%2F86%2F8`

We find it not acceptable to incorporate this on our site in this form. Can you help me by advising me what to do to present the user a confirmation screen?

thanks for helping, Ruud

Comment: I would say checkout your logs as a blank screen usually indicates some sort of error.

Comment: thank you Jaap, the log file certainly contains very useful information. I hope it is going to take me further. The location of the logfile is public_html/SITE/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

Comment: The last test registrations clearly show that after registration, when a blank screen appears (with or without Class __PHP_Incomplete_Class warning), no error or warning appears in the log, only confirmation lines. Nothing wrong there....

Comment: I mentioned that test payments don't work at all. That is not the case. They do not show up in the dashboard, which made me think the payment failed. But they are _supposed_ not to show up in the dashboard. They can be found by doing a contribution or participant search and checking the 'is Test' checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved after upgrading to civicrm 5.28 and omnimpay multiprocessor 3.13

Answer (score 1):

You must check cancel url and return/thankyou url before redirecting to payment processor site.

normally url pattern should be like https://domain.com/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/register&_qf_ThankYou_display=true&qfKey=dedf990ab5ff17ebff9f7cc370fbee49_6616

while "wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fpayment%2Fipn%2F86%2F8" is used as callback/webhook url to process the payment at civicrm side.

Comment: Hi Sunil, a wrong thankyou url sounds as a very plausible reason for the behaviour of the current behaviour of a payment. I have looked around in the event configuration, but found nothing about url's right there. Can you tell me where I can check that configuration? If you have a link to documentation concerning the url parameters that can be used (in you example), I'd be very grateful.

Comment: in the configuration, I found a section 'Thank you screen' though. This screen is never displayed. When should this be displayed?

Comment: @ruud thank you url is generated in code base , check 'CRM/Core/Payment/PayPalImpl.php' look for 'getReturnSuccessUrl' function, you need to implement and pass return/thankyou url to payment process site.

Comment: thank you Sunil for the explanation. I will dive into that and see what I can do.